# How to pass to Vue-JS several components?

Tags: vue.js

I can't understand should I create new instance of vue, or I can use one instance and put in it all needed components. If yes, how I can do it. Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var loginMenu = Vue.extend({
    template: `
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                      <img alt="Brand" src="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
              `
  })

  var pageFooter = Vue.extend({
    template: `
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
                </div>
              `
  })



  // register it with the tag <example>
  Vue.component('loginmenu', loginMenu),
  Vue.component('pagefooter', pageFooter)

  new Vue({
    el: '#loginmenu' //how pass another templates here??
  })


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main file, for example `index.html`, add a main js file, `app.js` in your app.js include all of your components. Something like this

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <loginmenu></loginmenu>
    <pagefooter></pagefooter>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var loginMenu = Vue.extend({
    template: `
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                      <img alt="Brand" src="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
              `
  })

  var pageFooter = Vue.extend({
    template: `
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
                </div>
              `
  })



  // register it with the tag <example>
  Vue.component('loginmenu', loginMenu),
  Vue.component('pagefooter', pageFooter)

  new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components:  {
        'loginmenu': loginMenu,
        'pagefooter', pageFooter
    }
  })
```